# How to Run a Command on the Serially Connected Device in python

Tags: python-2.7, serial-port

I Have Connected a Telepresence Device serially to my PC and it is connected successfully but i am not able to read or write the Data from the Device,Can Any Buddy Help me..
Here is my Python Script.I Need my script to Execute the command whatever i give in its command prompt.

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial()
ser.braudrate = 115200 
ser.port = "/dev/ttyUSB0" 
ser.open()
print ser.name

if ser.isOpen(): 
       print True 
elif ser.isOpen(): 
       print False 

ser.readall() 
print ser    

ser.write("hello\n")
print ser
```

Comment: Please provide the make/model of the device.

Comment: shane wealti, its an cisco's telepresence(video conference) named as C-90 device.

Comment: I recommend connecting to the device over a serial port using a terminal program first and verify that you have it working by typing the commands yourself. Once you have that working then you can move on to trying to send those same commands in your Python code.

Comment: Yes through minicom my command are working fine now the point is how to write those thing in python script/program.

Comment: What commands are you sending via mini-com and what is the response you are getting when you do that? Please show the actual command being sent in Minicom and how you are sending that same command in Python.

Comment: Here I have logined into Device through minicom</n>login: admin
Password: 
Welcome to 
Cisco Codec Release TC7.1.0.48db3d2
SW Release Date: 2014-03-28
*r Login successful

OK
HERE i have given a command which calls the other endpoint
xcommand Dial Number: 4164@10.78.23.19

OK
*r DialResult (status=OK): 
    CallId: 2
    ConferenceId: 1
** end
after entering into minicom i RUN this Command which executed successfully the same command i want to RUN through my python script. My serial connection is open but i am not able to read or write into that device.

Comment: So does your python code look for the login prompt and then send "admin" to log in and then look for the password prompt and respond to the password prompt with the correct password? I don't see that part in your code. Obviously don't post code with the actual password here but you need to show how you are reading and responding to those prompts in your python code.

Comment: Shane Wealti, The Problem is i am not able to open that prompt i don't know how to open username and password prompt. so you please suggest me how to open/get access to username and password prompt

Comment: 1) Open the port. 2) Loop trying to read bytes of data from the port. Add any bytes read to a buffer. Check the buffer for the username prompt. If you see the username prompt send the user name by writing it to the port. Continue doing this in a loop checking for data, processing any received data, and responding.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar problem right now, but, in your case, instead of using *ser.write()* I'd try using *ser.writelines*. If you are still looking for documentation try [here](http://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/pyserial_api.html).